# Place line beneath all lines in an edit text android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an edit text that is multiline.  I've set the number of lines to 5, but when the edit text draws, it shows blank lines, then the line which is standard for the edit text.  I would like to have a line drawn beneath all of the lines.  Here is the edit text:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/task_editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="Some text"
    android:lines="5"
    android:maxLines="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    />
```

The screen:

[image]

How to do this?

Comment: You would like to have the line drawn beneath all the lines? I don't quite understand what you are trying to accomplish here. Can you please clarify?

Comment: I'd like to draw a line underneath all the lines, individually.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know **there is no direct way** from `EditText` to under line all the lines.
Though there's a way,

Create a `multi_line.xml` in `drawable` and define all the lines you want in it (In this example only 5 lines defined)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:top="-60dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#000"/>
        <!--you can change the color or width of every single line-->
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:top="-20dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
 <item
     android:gravity="bottom"
        android:top="20dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
 <item
     android:gravity="bottom"
        android:top="60dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:top="100dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

The used values of `android:top` attribute 
(`-60dp`, `-20dp`, `20dp`, `60dp`, `100dp`) can be changed, depends on font size.

Then use `multi_line.xml` as `background`

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/task_editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="Some text"
    android:lines="5"
    android:maxLines="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:background="@drawable/multi_line"
    />
```

Note: This example is not tested on different screens.